# Handle multiple inputs with one onChange function handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a scenario where based on a number(tenure) i want to render tenure times an input field of date type.
how to get values of all inputs when they change?[these are the number of inputs based on tenure]

Comment: Do you have any code to show what you tried ? you can look at https://formik.org/ for form in reactjs.

Answer (score 1):

Presented below is one possible way to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;
const Thingy = ({...props}) => {
  // state to hold tenure (number) input from user
  const [tenure, setTenure] = useState(null);
  // state to hold tenure-dates (array of varying size)
  const [tnDates, setTnDates] = useState(null);

  // update tenure when user input changes
  const handleTenureChange = ev => setTenure(ev.target.value);
  
  // when 'tenure' gets updated, update the tenure-dates array
  useEffect(() => setTnDates(
    (tenure && tenure > 0)
      ? ( [...Array(+tenure).keys()].map(
        id => ({id, tenureDate: ''})
      )) : null
  ), [tenure]);
  
  // when user inputs a particular date, accept the input 
  // and update the specific element in the array
  const handleDateChange = ev => {
    const idx = ev.target.id;       // to access specific array element
    const val = ev.target.value;    // to access the date-value selected by user
    setTnDates(prev => {            // "prev" is the current array
      const nd = [...prev];         // shallow-copy "prev" into "nd" (new-data) array
      nd[idx].tenureDate = val;     // update the "tenureDate" at position "idx"
      return nd;                    // return the updated "nd" array to store into state
    });
  };
  
  // clear all fields
  const clearAllFields = () => setTenure(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <label>Tenure: </label>
      <input type='number' value={tenure}
        onChange={handleTenureChange}
      />
      {tenure && tenure > 0 ? (<div style={{ margin: '10px 0' }}>
        Select dates
        <div
          style={{
            display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column',
            width: '45%', marginTop: '10px'
          }}
        >{tnDates &&
          Array.isArray(tnDates) &&
          tnDates.length > 0 &&
          tnDates.map(
            ({id, tenureDate}) => (
              <input
                style={{ margin: '5px 0'}}
                key={id} id={id} type="date"
                value={tenureDate}
                onChange={handleDateChange}
              />
            )
        )}</div>
        <div style={{ marginTop: '10px' }}>
          Place buttons for futher processing here...
        </div>
        {tenure && tenure > 0 && tnDates && Array.isArray(tnDates) && (
          <div style={{ margin: '5px 0'}}>
            <button onClick={clearAllFields}>Clear All Fields</button>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>) : null}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <h3>DEMO</h3>
    <Thingy />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("rd")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="rd" />
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments added to the snippet above.

EDIT (29 OCT):

> do the same with radio buttons.please help

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;
const Thingy = ({...props}) => {
  // state to hold tenure (number) input from user
  const [tenure, setTenure] = useState(null);
  const [selectedRadio, setSelectedRadio] = useState(-1);

  // update tenure when user input changes
  const handleTenureChange = ev => setTenure(ev.target.value);
  
  // clear selection
  const selectNone = () => setSelectedRadio(-1);
  
  // clear all fields
  const clearAllFields = () => (setSelectedRadio(-1), setTenure(0));

  return (
    <div>
      <label>Tenure: </label>
      <input type='number' value={tenure}
        onChange={handleTenureChange}
      />
      {tenure && tenure > 0 ? (<div style={{ margin: '10px 0' }}>
        Radio Button Options
        <div
          style={{
            display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column',
            width: '45%', marginTop: '10px'
          }}
        >{tenure && tenure > 0 &&
          [...Array(+tenure).keys()].map(
            id => (
            <div>
              <input
                style={{ margin: '5px 0'}}
                key={id} id={id} type="radio"
                name={'groupName'} value={id}
                checked={id === selectedRadio}
                onChange={() => setSelectedRadio(id)}
              />
              <label for={id}>Radio Option Label {id+1}</label>
            </div>
            )
        )}<br/><br/>{
          (selectedRadio >= 0) && 
          `Selection Option is: Radio Option Label ${+selectedRadio+1}`
        }
        </div>
        
        <div style={{ marginTop: '10px' }}>
          Place buttons for futher processing here...
        </div><br/>
        {tenure && tenure > 0 && (
          <div style={{ margin: '5px 0'}}>
            <button onClick={selectNone}>Clear Selection</button>{" "}
            <button onClick={clearAllFields}>Clear All Fields</button>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>) : null}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <h3>DEMO</h3>
    <Thingy />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("rd")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="rd" />
```

Comment: how to clear all the fields on a single button click

Comment: button added to clear all fields when tenure is above 0. On single click, tenure gets set to zero, and all dates are cleared.

Comment: Hi I am not able to do the same with radio buttons.please help

Comment: @RohitRai, you may want to post a new question with the exact specifics as well as the current progress you've already done. It will help other members to also review & support.

Comment: @jsNoob , as suggested i have new question. below is the link                                          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74243883/how-to-handle-multiple-radio-button-inputs-with-one-onchange-function-handler

Answer (score 0):

You can add an input element for tenure, then add input field for taking dates dynamically. For each date input you can bind 'change' event on which you can collect values of all dates. Finally add those dynamically created inputs in div with id 'container'

For e.g

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="number" onchange="tenureChange(this.value)" />
    <div id="container"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function tenureChange(value) {
        let n = value || 0;
        n = parseInt(n);

        let inputsArray = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          const input = document.createElement("input");
          input.type = "date";
          input.classList.add("date-input");
          input.addEventListener("change", () => {
            const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".date-input");
            inputs.forEach((input) => console.log(input.value));
          });
          inputsArray.push(input);
        }
        document.getElementById("container").replaceChildren(...inputsArray);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```