# How to Handle multiple radio button inputs with one onChange function handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i have a scenario where based on a number(say numberOfFlags) i want to render numberOfFlags times an radio button group.Each group has two radio buttons approve and reject as per screen[image]shot attached how to get values of all inputs when they change?
An lastly i have to store result of all radio buttons (approve/reject) in an array and send to API

Answer (score 1):

You need to use two parameters on onChange function. One is for current index and another is for Approve/Reject.
Like below code snippet

```
onchange = handleOnChage(index, isApproveClicked)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this in many different ways, but I would probably simple create a state with an array of values in the parent component and pass it to each and every item to toggle its own state depending action.

App.js

```
export function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([false, false, false]);
  const updateItem = (value, index) => {
    let copyList = [...list];
    copyList[index] = !value;
    setList(copyList);
  };
  console.log(list)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {list && (
        <>
          {list.map((value, index) => (
            <Item values={[value, index]} updateItem={updateItem} key={index+"_check"} />
          ))}
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Item.js

```
export default function Item({ values, updateItem }) {
  return (
    <>
      <input
        onChange={() => updateItem(values[0], values[1])}
        type="checkbox"
        checked={values[0] ? "checked" : ""}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presented below is one possible way to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const {useState} = React;
const Thingy = ({...props}) => {
  // num-of-flags is obtained from props
  const { numOfFlags: nf} = props || {};
  // if it is null or not above 0, return "invalid" message to parent
  if (!(nf && nf > 0)) return "invalid num-of-flags";
  // state variable to store approve/reject status
  const [statusObj, setStatusObj] = useState({});
  // JSX to render the UI & handle events
  return (
    <div>
      {([...Array(nf).keys()].map(grpIdx => (
        <div className="grpBox">
          Group num {grpIdx+1} <br/>
          <input type='radio' name={grpIdx} id={grpIdx} value={'approve'}
           onChange={() => setStatusObj({
            ...statusObj, [grpIdx]: 'approve',
           })}
          />
          <label for={grpIdx}>Approve</label>{" "}
          <input type='radio' name={grpIdx} id={grpIdx} value={'reject'}
           onChange={() => setStatusObj({
            ...statusObj, [grpIdx]: 'reject',
           })}
          />
          <label for={grpIdx}>Reject</label>
        </div>
      )))}<br/>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          // make API call here
          // for verification, displaying an alert-message showing the status
          const displayMsg = [...Array(nf).keys()].map(
            gi => "Group num " + (+gi+1) + " : " + (gi in statusObj ? statusObj[gi] : '__')
          ).join(', ');
          alert(`Approve-Reject status is: ${JSON.stringify(displayMsg)}`);
        }}
      >
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <div className="demoTitle">DEMO</div>
    <Thingy numOfFlags={5} />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("rd")
);
```

```css
.demoTitle {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.grpBox {
  margin: 5px; padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid purple;
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="rd" />
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments added to the snippet above.

PS: If you'd like to add value to stackoverflow community,

Comment: i want to store these values in an array instead of object.how can i do that??

Comment: what should the value be when neither approved, nor rejected are selected? And, what should each element of the array be - should they be just string (like `approved`, `rejected`) or should they be object (like `{optionId: 0, status: 'approved'}`).